# Checked out file was ignored on merge

Tags: merge, perforce

I merged trunk to my dev branch several times.
Now I see that some files don't have changes made in branch.
Those files were checked out (with my local changes) when I done merges.
Now if I try to merge only one file (_trunk->devbranch) Perforce doesn't show any changes.
If I merge back to trunk Perforce deletes changes made in trunk.
What's the best way to merge lost changes to dev branch and then back to trunk?

Comment: Did you run 'resolve' after you ran 'merge'? If your files were checked out when you merged, Perforce won't overwrite your changes. Instead, it schedules a merge of your changes with the trunk changes, which you can perform by running the 'resolve' command.

Comment: Yes I've ran resolve. But I had not submitted those files (my files).